# ASP.NET and jQuery AJAX - strange problem

Tags: asp.net, jquery, iis-7, web-services

I've got this strange problem...

I've got a web service running against jQuery front-end. When I run it through the integrated web server of VS2008 - it works great.
But when I use the IIS itself - I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: application/json; charset=utf-8.
>    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
>    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

the code for the AJAX:

`$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/MYSITE/WEBSERVICE.asmx/SOME_FUNCTION",
            data: '{ prm1: "' + p1+ '", prm2: "' + p2+ '", prm3: "' + p3+ '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
.....`

Any ideas why this happens?

The site is .NET 3.5 using "integrated managed pipeline pool".

Thanks,
Roman

Answer (score 4):

Got the answer...

I've added httphandler and httpmodule to web.config but didn't add them to system.webserver as handlers and modules.

maybe will help someone

roman